# How to fix SQL syntax near JOIN?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am fighting with a syntax error and I can't really find the problem.

this is my query

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta PM1
  WHERE PM1.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude'
  AND PM1.post_id = '$id'
  JOIN wp_postmenta PM2 
  WHERE PM2.post_id = PM1.post_id 
  AND PM2.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_longitude'
```

and getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN wp_postmeta PM2' at line 3

could please someone can give me a hint what i'm missing?

Comment: The error message does not seem to be corresponding with the query you are showing

Comment: I think you might have a problem with `AND PM1.post_id = '$id'` unless `$id` is the actual value in your table. Have you tried `AND PM1.post_id = ". $id`?

Answer (score 6):

First have to come the join then the rest of the query. So something like

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta PM1
  JOIN wp_postmenta PM2 on PM1.post_id = PM2.post_id
  WHERE PM1.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude'
  AND PM1.post_id = '$id'
  AND PM2.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_longitude'
```

Answer (score 3):

You've two where clauses and the join order is wrong:

```
select ...
from ...
join ... on ...
where ... and ...
```